# SQL Server Delete on read

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there an easy way in SQLServer touse data as READ_ONCE? What I mean is, can I set it to delete a row after it has selected it?

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? Sounds like a unique use case. Also, what about spurious/eager reads?

Comment: Not for me, for a friend. His req's require him to read info and then delete it. Who knows why, but it is what he needs to be able to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read it with `DELETE ... OUTPUT ...`. This is how queues work.

Answer (score 5):

Off the top of my head, the only way I can think of would be to restrict all logins to prohiibit any Select access, and only allow access through a stored procedure "FetchMyWhateverData" and then delete the rows as second SQL statement inside the stored proc.

```
CreateProcedure FetchMyWhateverData
@MyEntityId Integer,
As
Set NoCount On

    Select * From TableName 
    Where Id = @MyEntityId 

    Delete TableName 
    Where Id = @MyEntityId 

    Return 0
```

-- and adding in the other appropriate infrastructure code of course.

Comment: Unfortunately, constraints we have been given do not allow us to create procs. This was a solution we had thought of. I apologize for not being more explicit in question.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this easily if the data is accessed through a stored procedure. You can select the data into a temp table, delete the data and return the temp. All wrapped in a transaction of course.